# No 3D processing OpenGL unknown ATI Radeon 200 Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: amd-graphics, opengl, 3d, blender

Any one who could tell me how to make OpenGL work, I need to open Blender3D. I have already purged the Nvidia firmware and installed the ATI only. It worked in some way it went from no OpenGL to unknown provider, but seems to be more fluent in 2D drawing. thus my concern how to enable OpenGL? Do I have to configure some parameters or libraries or what?
my pc specs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB400 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:14.6 Modem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB400 AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 02)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
05:02.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 03)
05:09.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx21/x515 Cardbus
```

- GPU: ATI mobility Radeon 200m
- CPU: AMD Sempron

This is what Linux says about my GPU:

```
*-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: RS480M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       id físico: 5
       información del bus: pci@0000:01:05.0
       versión: 00
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 66MHz
       capacidades: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=radeon latency=66 mingnt=8
       recursos: irq:17 memoria:c8000000-cfffffff ioport:9000(size=256) memoria:c0100000-c010ffff memoria:c0000-dffff
```

*update*
 -1
down vote
accept

i found this little log that blender recorded in /tmp/blender.crash.log
Blender 2.79 (sub 0), Unknown revision
backtrace

blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x37) [0x19bd5e7] blender(+0xac16d7) [0xf346d7] linux-gate.so.1(__kernel_sigreturn+0) [0xb7f52d14] [0xa87ec254] /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so(+0x4e7f48) [0x92b05f48]

I still unable to make it run, why in knoppix 7.6.1 it works fluently, ***YES BLENDER 2.79 V*** how?! there is a way the knoppix developer found it so it means there is an easy way because koppix runs in live and installs every-thing any firmware all works just right but how?! and do not get me wrong but im still looking and im taking action in testing firmware and i really want to help others with the same problem (i know this is not permitted but thank you Eskander for correcting my spelling)

Comment: You did not run blender >= 2.77 on this GPU, regardless of OS. It requires OpenGL 2.1, and the GPU you list only supports up to 2.0. The only way it would work would be entirely in software rendering.

Comment: Why don't you ask the Knoppix devs how they managed to enable it to work then? You cannot run something that requires a newer thing than the card supports, on that card. And again, Knoppix 7.6.1 does not include Blender 2.79 which came out much later. I'd suggest you try latest Knoppix release and test again if that's what you think you did, but I am telling you it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This GPU only supports up to OpenGL 2.0, and is 14 years old.

Blender 2.77 and newer requires at least OpenGL 2.1. You maybe able to download 2.76 or an older version and use it on this GPU though, as older Blender versions only require OpenGL 1.4.

See https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

You may be able to run newer versions of Blender with only software rendering, by setting the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` environment variable to `true`:

```
#: export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true
```

Comment: i will try but i ran it in this system with Knoppix 7.6.1 (a week ago) i ran blender 2.79 and im wondering how that distro is able to make this whole computer work in live mode currently im using lubuntu so if that distro is having the firmware and makes it work i shoul be able to make it work in any other linux distro i suppose (why i do not swith to knoppix? because it has a ton of software that i do not need and it does not letme purge anythin does not letme modify enything and it uses other storage type a beta one isntead of ext3 )

Comment: The current knoppix release is 8.3, not 7.6.1. Most likely 7.6.1 has blender 2.76, because newer versions of blinder will not work on your card. You cannot add a new version of OpenGL to the card.

Comment: And in fact, knoppix 7.6.1 was released months before blender 2.77 was. Therefore it most likely was 2.76, which works on OpenGL 1.4, as my answer states.

Comment: yes but i was able to run 2.79 in knoppix 7.6.1 but how?! there should be a way, but how?!

Comment: No, you weren't. Not on this GPU anyway.

Comment: i did it in the same system with different os